# How can Turtlebot be simulated with turtlebot arm package?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simulate turtlebot arm attached to turtlebot but i dont know how to do that, Can someone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228576/how-can-turtlebot-be-simulated-with-turtlebot-arm-package?/) by [hammadasifalvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24281/hammadasifalvi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there's quite a lot of things to do. I did them in [this package](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_simulation). You can start trying to launch [this file](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_simulation/launch/thorp_playground.launch) that just starts a Turtlebot with an arm (and other stuff) in the same playground scenario used on turtlebot navigation demos.

You will have to install quite a lot of dependencies....  If you want to use all my stuff from the beginning, follow [this README](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/README.md) to replicate my workspace. If not, well, just borrow the parts you need and install the dependencies roslaunch will complain about, or better use rosdep to install them in a blow.

Probably I'll miss something, but as far as I can remember, you need:

- xacro file that includes both a turtlebot and a turtlebot arm (mine is [here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_bringup/urdf/thorp.urdf.xacro))
- xacro file with all the extra information gazebo needs to control the turtlebot arm, like controller plugins and transmissions (mine is [here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_bringup/urdf/thorp.urdf.xacro))
- spawn ROS controllers as described in a yaml file (mine is [here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_simulation/param/arm_control.yaml))

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2016-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hammadasifalvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24281/hammadasifalvi/) on 2016-03-10**:
Thanks forge, Can these files work with turtlebot 1?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2016-03-10**:
Well.... you are simulating a Turtlebot2 with a turtlebot arm. To simulate a Turtlebot1, the xacro file that includes both a turtlebot and a turtlebot arm must describe your robot, instead of mine. Apart from that, the rest should be pretty the same

**Comment by [RedJohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/34830/redjohn/) on 2018-04-26**:
Hi, did you manage to simulate your arm in Gazebo? I'm having the same issue, but I can't run the example from jorge. Thank you.